# Build creation issue with monkey talk iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, monkeytalk

Through my Jenkins server,I do instrumentation of my iOS project with monkey talk related jar automatically.Once this is done then through ant (.xml),smoke test gets automatically triggered for the application.

```
xcodebuild -project app/XXX.xcodeproj -target XXX1 VALID_ARCHS=i386 -arch i386 -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.1 -xcconfig /opt/monkeytalk/MonkeyTalk.xcconfig build
```

Below is .xconfig file content.Now,when I am keeping this config file as it is with no change in it then build is failing(which is triggered via Jenkins).

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -force_load /opt/monkeytalk/libMonkeyTalk.a -force_load /opt/monkeytalk/xxx.a -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -lsqlite3
```

But as soon as I am changing .xconfig file to below statement,then Jenkins is successful in creating the build,but this time monkey talk is not able to communicate with the application.

```
-force_load /opt/monkeytalk/libMonkeyTalk.a -force_load /opt/monkeytalk/xxx.a -framework CFNetwork -framework QuartzCore -lsqlite3
```

Below are some log statements for this issue

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XXXCrashManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in UIViewController+Breadcrumbs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXXXXX.app/XXXXX normal i386
```

Any kind of hint suggestion is welcomed.

Regards,

Comment: can any one provide me some hints also,can any one ask more details if they want.

Comment: its better to provide the reason for down vote don't just do that.if you know the answer of this problem tell me.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to assume that this was working before, but now it's broken. I just ran into this when attempting to build the target monkeyTalk is linked to. I had to go to the linker in.. Target --> Build Settings --> Linking.

I removed the -all_load link and loaded the necessary links from the prod target and rebuilt. Then I saw the monkeytalk lib load.

I'm also assuming you setup monkeytalk via the ios documentation on their site.

I'm not saying this is going to fix your problem, but I think this will get you in the right direction.

Best,

Comment: so you removed -all_load and -ObjC linkning commmand from build settings.Then how you are able to load the monkey talk files later on.how you are sure that your monkey talk files are loaded.

Comment: The console output tells me that the monkeytalk agent it running. And the fact that the tests run help too.